# Cell Selection Methods R1C1 or?

Tags: excel, vba

I stumbled on this accidently and haven't been able to find an answer online.
These 2 similar looking lines of code give very different results.
I'm ok with the R1C1 version. Can you help me understand and name the other?
Many thanks for your time,
Paul

```
Sub testcells()

Cells(1, 2).Select
Cells(1)(2).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as `Cells(1, 2)` is shorthand for:
`Cells.Item(1, 2)`

so `Cells(1)(2)` is shorthand for:

`Cells.Item(1).Item(2)`

`Cells.Item(1)` returns range A1, and the second Item property is relative to A1 so you get A2. It is the same as using:
`range("A1").Range("A2")`

A couple of things to note:

1. The start cell doesn't have to be A1 - for example, `cells(2)(3)`
   refers to B3 (the first step gets B1, then the 3 takes you to B3)
2. If you only specify one number for the Item property, the result
   depends on the width of the original range as the count goes from
   left to right and top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question. Not Sure, Just my observation (Maybe later someone will clarify more):

`Cells(1,2)` is in rowindex,colindex which you are ok with.

`Cells(1)(2)` is cell number 1 in the respective range, with vertical(row) offset (offset is like 2,3,4... for downward cell or 0,-1,-2,... for upward cell). Without preceding range, `Cells(1)(2)` becomes number 1 cell in worksheet, with downward offset 1 (not 2!)

Summary:

`Cells(1,2)` is B1 and `Cells(1)(2)` is A2

Fun Part: I have tried `Cells(1)(2)()()..` works every figure inside bracket is treated as offset to previous one!! Except the first (1), of course.